# cannot understand the definition of "row-major-ref" in sbcl

Tags: common-lisp, sbcl

The definition is from src/code/array.lisp of sbcl. It looks like an infinite loop? I didn't find any clue to get it. Any hint? Thank you!

```
(defun row-major-aref (array index)                                                  |
  #!+sb-doc                                                                          |
  "Return the element of array corressponding to the row-major index. This is        |
   SETF'able."                                                                       |
  (declare (optimize (safety 1)))                                                    |
  (row-major-aref array index))
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In `src/compiler/array-tran.lisp` you can also find this code:

```
(deftransform row-major-aref ((array index))
  `(hairy-data-vector-ref array
                          (%check-bound array (array-total-size array) index)))
```

I'm not an expert in SBCL internals, but I assume that `row-major-aref` is treated by the compiler as the "basic" operation that is not reduced to other Lisp function calls, but rather transformed to machine code.

Comment: One of the ways, are so called VirtualOPerations, which give assembler implementations for function calls, which are used for calls with certain fixed argument types. They are found in compiler/<target>/ as `DEFINE-VOP` macros invocations with the property `:translate`. This property states which function they implement (for certain argument types).